# How login is possible, if I deny login page via .htaccess with allow ip

Tags: wp-admin, htaccess

I am running a wordpress website, with AIO WP Security & Firewall plugin which inform me if there is a wrong login attempts.

/wp-admin contain a .htaccess where I set:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 123.123.123.123 // my IP
```

I still get emails from AIO Plugin that someone tried login with a strange Username from a different IP.

Is there another way how to get the login page an try to authenticate other than /wp-admin ??

Answer (score 2):

You have denied the access to `/wp-admin`, however the user can still attempt to login via `wp-login`:

```
http://example.com/wp-login.php
```

Therefore, you should also deny `wp-login.php`:

```
<Files "wp-login.php">
    Order allow,deny
    deny from all
    allow from 123.123.123.123 // Your IP address
</Files>
```

Comment: Well ok, if I add this I get Apaches 403. but when I rename /wp-admin to /myadmin the URL http://example.com/wp-login.php lead to 404 page. Why I still get access probe emails?